# Deleting state and getting new state problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

On deleting a favorite from a React app, it deletes the dish, but throws an error

> const favorites = props.favorites.favorites[0].dishes.map((dish), {.. TypeError: Cannot read property 'dishes' of undefined ...

after reload of the app, it shows the remaining non-deleted dishes only (works fine)

in main component passing props 'favorite' to the favorite component as

```
<Favorites
  favorites={this.props.favorites}
  deleteFavorite={this.props.deleteFavorite}
/>
```

in favorite component checking the props result and passing the props to render menu component

```
if (props.favorites.favorites) {
  const favorites = props.favorites.favorites[0].dishes.map((dish) => {
    return (
      <div key={dish._id} className="col-12 mt-5">
        <RenderMenuItem dish={dish} deleteFavorite={props.deleteFavorite} />
      </div>
    );
  })
```

render menu component receives above passed props

```
function RenderMenuItem({ dish, deleteFavorite }) {
  return (
    <Media tag="li">
      <Media left middle>
        <Media object src={baseUrl + dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
      </Media>
      <Media body className="ml-5">
        <Media heading>{dish.name}</Media>
        <p>{dish.description}</p>
        <Button outline color="danger" onClick={() => deleteFavorite(dish._id)}>
           <span className="fa fa-times"></span>
        </Button>
      </Media>
    </Media>
  );
}
```

action creator for favorites item deleting

```
export const deleteFavorite = (dishId) => (dispatch) => {
const bearer = "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token");

return fetch(baseUrl + "favorites/" + dishId, {
  method: "DELETE",
  headers: {
    Authorization: bearer,
  },
  credentials: "same-origin",
 })
  .then(
    (response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response;
      } else {
       var error = new Error(
         "Error " + response.status + ": " + response.statusText
       );
       error.response = response;
       throw error;
     }
   },
    (error) => {
      throw error;
    }
  )
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((favorites) => {
   // console.log("Favorite Deleted", favorites);
   dispatch(addFavorites(favorites));
  })
   .catch((error) => dispatch(favoritesFailed(error.message)));
};
     
export const favoritesLoading = () => ({
  type: ActionTypes.FAVORITES_LOADING,
}); 

export const favoritesFailed = (errmess) => ({
  type: ActionTypes.FAVORITES_FAILED,
  payload: errmess,
});

export const addFavorites = (favorites) => ({
  type: ActionTypes.ADD_FAVORITES,
  payload: favorites,
});
```

reducer for favorites item

```
import * as ActionTypes from "./ActionTypes";

export const favorites = (
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
    errMess: null,
    favorites: null,
  },
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.ADD_FAVORITES:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        errMess: null,
        favorites: action.payload,
      };

    case ActionTypes.FAVORITES_LOADING:
      return { ...state, isLoading: true, errMess: null, favorites: null };

    case ActionTypes.FAVORITES_FAILED:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        errMess: action.payload,
        favorites: null,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your REST DELETE method. It returns probably something different from an array (an object, maybe the deleted one, I suppose).

So after calling this DELETE you are using its response and you are setting your `favorites` in redux store to this response. As it is not an array, there is nothing defined at `props.favorites.favorites[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Just because `props.favorites.favorites` exists, is defined, and not null, ***does not*** also mean that it is an array nor that it is populated, e.g. that `props.favorites.favorites[0]` is defined.

You can check that the complete path to the `dishes` array is accessible:

```
if (props.favorites.favorites?.[0]?.dishes) {
  const favorites = props.favorites.favorites[0].dishes.map((dish) => {
    return (
      <div key={dish._id} className="col-12 mt-5">
        <RenderMenuItem dish={dish} deleteFavorite={props.deleteFavorite} />
      </div>
    );
  });

  ...

}
```

If you cannot use the Optional Chaining operator then use null-checks/guard-clauses instead:

```
if (
  props.favorites.favorites &&
  props.favorites.favorites[0] &&
  props.favorites.favorites[0].dishes
) {
  const favorites = props.favorites.favorites[0].dishes.map((dish) => {
    return (
      <div key={dish._id} className="col-12 mt-5">
        <RenderMenuItem dish={dish} deleteFavorite={props.deleteFavorite} />
      </div>
    );
  });

  ...

}
```